# Executing jmeter.sh in Windows

Tags: jmeter

In [Running JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running) jmeter.bat is defined for windows

> To run JMeter, run the jmeter.bat (for Windows) or jmeter (for Unix) file. These files are found in the bin directory.

I'm able to run also `jmeter.sh` in windows using [Git Bash](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html) and it's working fine.

Are there any benefits or issues in executing jmeter.sh on windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefits is that Git Bash is not provided OOTB on Windows while regular bat is.

Except for this, since git bash is a shell emulator which looks rather serious, I guess it should work fine.

Did you try it at high load to see if you face any limits ?

Also you can see some comparison of Windows shells:

- https://macyves.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/hipsterising-windows-cygwin-vs-babun-vs-git-bash-vs-powershell-the-onion-scale/

Comment: Currently it's used as a workaround, I'll update if needed